# ERROR: function date_trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have this problem. I have an sql query am trying to make to my postgres db. These queries work fine in oracle but am in the process of converting it to a postgres query but it complains. This is the query:

```
select  to_char(calldate,'Day') as Day, date_trunc(calldate) as transdate,
Onnet' as destination,ceil(sum(callduration::integer/60) )as    total_minutes,round(sum(alltaxcost::integer) ,2)as revenue
from cdr_data 
where callclass ='008' and callsubclass='001'
and callduration::integer >0
and  regexp_like(identifiant,'^73')
and bundleunits = 'Money'
and inserviceresultindicator in (0,5)
and regexp_like(regexp_replace(callednumber,'^256','') ,'^73')
group by  to_char(calldate,'Day') ,trunc(calldate),'Onnet' order by 2
```

And the error am getting is this:

```
Err] ERROR:  function date_trunc(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 4: select  to_char(calldate,'Day') as Day, date_trunc(calldate)...
```

What am I doing wrong, or what is the solution to this error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
... date_trunc('day',calldate) ...
```

For PostgreSQL `date_trunc()` function you must always specify precision as the first argument.

Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: Works fine but then throws another error: [Err] ERROR:  function regexp_like(character varying, unknown) does not exist
LINE 9: and  regexp_like(identifiant,'^73')

Comment: @roykasa Try replacing `regexp_like(regexp_replace(callednumber,'^256','') ,'^73')` with `regexp_replace(callednumber,'^256','') ~ '^73'`. Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

Comment: Ok got the hang of regexp and it works ok but throws one more error: [Err] ERROR:  non-integer constant in GROUP BY
LINE 13: ..._char(calldate,'Day') ,date_trunc('day',calldate),'Onnet' or...

Comment: `'Onnet'` is just a `text` constant, where `Onnet` or `"Onnet"` will be one of the `cdr_data` columns (if a read the query correctly). Details on escaping literals [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Ahh dont worry about it. I solved it. thank you so much though

Comment: Oh one more thing, how can i replace this query with its postgres equivalent? and  regexp_like(identifiant,'^73')

Comment: @roykasa Try `identifiant ~ '^73'`. The same `regexp_like` is in the second comment to this question.